# WPF + ListBox Databinding system.data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to fill Listbox after fetching data from the database in WPF application.

I have a class that return DataTable

```
class DataBaseTable
{
    MySqlConnection connection;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    public DataTable GetTable(String query, String sortBy)
    {
        String connString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=MyNewPass123;database=samprojects;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = sortBy;          
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

And the XAML code

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1" Width="150" Height="150" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

And Main Window Class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DataBaseTable dbTable = new DataBaseTable();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listbox1.DataContext = dbTable.GetTable("select name from projects", "name");            
    }
}
```

But my List Box is getting filled with

```
  System.Data.DataRowView
  System.Data.DataRowView
  System.Data.DataRowView
```

Not able to get what is getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the control will show the .ToString() of the object. since it's a datarowview it shows the assembly name only. what you want is setting the DisplayMemberPath

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1" Width="150" Height="150" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="MyColumn"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox1" Width="150" Height="150" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

There is also more information on the subject here:

[Data Templates](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html)

Comment: The other answer suits your needs more. this technique is more useful if you have more than one column in your datatable and you want to bind more than one control to different values.

Comment: Yes Ric is right, when dealing with more than 1 value to display you will have to use this method.